# Insert rows using awk

Tags: shell, awk

How can I insert a row using awk?

My file looks as:

```
1       43
2       34
3       65
4       75
```

I would like to insert three rows with "?" So my desire file looks as:

```
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       43
5       34
6       65
7       75
```

I am trying with the below script.

```
awk '{if(NR<=3){print "NR        ?"}} {printf" " NR      $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{s="       "; for(c=1; c<4; c++) print c s "?"}
       {print c s $2; c++}' ip.txt 
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       43
5       34
6       65
7       75
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "1 ?\n2 ?\n3 ?\n"} {printf "%d", $1 + 3; printf " %s\n", $2}' file.txt
1 ?
2 ?
3 ?
4 43
5 34
6 65
7 75
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the 3 lines before awk, e.g.:

```
{ seq 3; cat file.txt; } | awk 'NR <= 3 { $2 = "?" } $1 = NR' OFS='\t'
```

Output:

```
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       43
5       34
6       65
7       75
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
1       43
2       34
3       65
4       75
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="       "}NR==1{print 1,"?";print 2,"?";print 3,"?"}{print NR+3,$2}' file.txt
```

output

```
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       43
5       34
6       65
7       75
```

Explanation: I set output field separator (`OFS`) to 7 spaces. For 1st row I do print three lines which consisting of subsequent number and `?` sheared by output field separator. You might elect to do this using `for` loop, especially if you expect that requirement might change here. For every line I print number of row plus 4 (to keep order) and 2nd column (`$2`). Thanks to use of OFS, you would need to make only one change if requirement regarding number of spaces will be altered. Note that construct like

```
{if(condition){dosomething}}
```

might be written in `GNU AWK` in more concise manner as

```
(condition){dosomething}
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*